# Where can I find Chinese language soft subtitles for domestic television programs?

Tags: resources

I am looking for Chinese language soft subtitles for domestic tv dramas (e.g. 白夜追凶) for language learning purposes. While domestic tv has captions hardcoded onto the broadcast, it is inconvenient to use these with dictionary tools as handwriting recognition is cumbersome and optical character recognition is unreliable.

Search engine efforts have not been fruitful as the vast majority of Chinese language soft subtitles appear to be for foreign media.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath for soft subtitles for domestic TV. There isn't much use for them for anyone apart from learners really. Foreign TV & movies on the other hand, has tons and tons of resources.

Comment: True but I was hoping that someone might know of a source since the sinosphere internet is large. For example, Soft subtitles for domestic TV are common in Japan since their broadcast television networks transmit captions for the hearing disabled on a different transport stream.

Comment: When you say "soft subtitles", do you actually mean [**closed captions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning)? The technical term for subtitles that are always visible is **open captions**.

Comment: Thank you and yes. The nomenclature I am employing is from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(captioning)#Types
No, "open captions" are not what I am seeking. Those are readily available in domestic broadcast content.

Answer (score 1):

[image: example]

Are you looking for subtitles like this?
You can try to [link](http://subhd.com/search0/%E7%99%BD%E5%A4%9C%E8%BF%BD%E5%87%B6)

Comment: Thanks but that site is for _foreign_ media, not _domestic_ media. All the entries for 白夜追凶 are not the 2017 domestic tv drama but the 2002 foreign film "Insomnia" of the same (translated) title. It's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't any site dedicated to translate Chinese to English. But there are some programs on YouTube that has bilingual subtitles. Try searching for iApartment on YouTube, it's a show like Friends.